# Can anyone tell me the name of this flower?

Tags: identification, flowers

I have came across this flower in Turkey Bodrum and I would like to know the name of this flower.

[image: flower]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It is a Passiflora, it seems Passiflora 'Incense'.  If you look in [Wikipedia-Passiflora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passiflora), you will see a very similar photo of your flower.